# Modifying scope not working without $scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for a button, which when clicked displays a loading screen.

```
angular.module('randomButton', ['Data'])

.directive('randomButton', function(Data) {
     return {
        scope: '=',
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'templates/components/randomButton.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            element.click(function(){
                scope._loading();
            });

        }
    }
});
```

It does this by calling another function on the scope contained within a different directive:

```
angular.module('quoteContainer', [])

.directive('quoteContainer', function(Data) {

    function quoteController($scope){

        $scope._loading = function(){
            console.log('loading');
            $scope.loadMessage = Data.getRandomText();
            $scope.loading = true;              
        };

    }

    return {
        scope: '=',
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'templates/components/quoteContainer.html',
        controller: ['$scope', quoteController],
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){

        }
    }
});
```

My problem is, for this change to occur, I'm having to call `$scope.$apply` within the `._loading()` function. For example:

```
$scope._loading = function(){
    console.log('loading');
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.loadMessage = Data.getRandomText();
        $scope.loading = true;              
    });         
};
```

I understand this is bad practice, and should only be used when interfacing with other frameworks/ajax calls etc. So why does my code refuse to work without `$scope.$apply`, and how can I make it work without it?

Comment: try to use angular functionality, such as an `ng-click` directive, rather than jquery (`click()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to let angular know some way of the change happening, because since it's in an asynchronous event handler, angular's usual mechanisms for noticing changes are not applying to it.

Hence the need to wrap it in `$apply`, which triggers a digest cycle after your code has run, giving angular a chance to make changes according to the new data. However, the preferred way of doing this is using angular's built-in [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service, which effectively does the same (i.e. wrapping your code in an `$apply` block), but doesn't have problems with the possibility that an other digest cycle might be ongoing when it's triggered.

You can use it the same way as you're currently using $apply:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.loadMessage = Data.getRandomText();
    $scope.loading = true;              
});
```

(It can take a second parameter if you actually want to delay the application of the values, but it's not necessary in your case.)

Comment: So every time I want to modify a variable on the scope (that's not being watched) I have to call $timeout? Seems like a really strange way of doing things.

Comment: Only if the source of the change is outside the angular framework (in this case, a browser interaction). When you have a "regular" call to a $scope function, angular will know about the changes and update the views without need for $timeout or $apply - this should be the majority of your cases, $timeout being the odd-one-out.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing this up for me! So just to make sure I've got it, external changes means I should use $timeout, internal changes should be taken care of?